# WebGL triangle layout for deformation

Tags: three.js, webgl, vertex, gl-triangle-strip

I am implementing simple deformation in WebGL by moving vertices up or down, but stumbled upon a problem with the way the triangles are laid out.

I am using the [`PlaneGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry) in `three.js` and it uses the [following layout](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/da2936540a48774b043a1e617bddbdce5102e417/src/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js#L93-L111) for the triangles:

```
indices.push( a, b, d )
indices.push( b, c, d )
```

[image: Vertices layout]
The layout used by `three.js` is on the left. Mine alternates between both.

Moving vertices up or down results in the **image on the left**, where, after moving the vertex, the deformation looks off. The blue dot represents the center vertex.
[image: Triangle layout top view]
I decided to alternate the triangles using the following code:

```
      if ( ( ix + iy ) % 2 === 0 ) {
        // Even segment
        indices.push( a, b, d )
        indices.push( b, c, d )
      } else {
        // Odd segment
        indices.push( a, b, c )
        indices.push( a, c, d )
      }
```

As you can see **on the right**, it gives me a much better result.

[image: Triangle layout diagonal view]
The two questions I have are:

- **Is the layout I used valid and what is its name?**
- **Is there a better better way to solve this problem?**

Comment: the term you might be looking for instead of "layout" could be "topology" in context of meshes. I'm curious though if there are terms for this specific example.

Comment: Thanks @pailhead, I'm in the same boat, it proves to be difficult for me to find information about something I don't know the name of! I will try adding _topology_ to my search queries.

Comment: You are considering alternate tessellations of the plane. You can also begin with a regular grid, and tessellate each grid cell into four triangles. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6920/files.

Comment: damn, right, tessellation is it

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley! That and the discussion around on Github are very interesting! Especially the demo at the end linked by user _makc_ with an isometric grid. Do you know why the type of tessellation I displayed on the left is the default? My gut would say "It is probably faster and produces acceptable results in most cases", but I do wonder.

Comment: No, I am not aware of a reason.

Comment: I’d say it’s because it’s much easier to “weave” a grid like mesh like this, every quad cell is the same, while you would have to apply extra logic.